# Make plotly display only the data mentioned by the user without reloading

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, visualization, plotly-express

I have to make an interactive application. Plotly will display the data from a pandas dataset only in a range given by the user during the program's runtime. My original approach was taking the range everytime the user changes it, modifying the dataset given to plotly based on those conditions and having plotly generate a new plot. But since the dataset is huge, its becoming very expensive.

Since I used plotly express to make the plots, it would be very helpful if the solutions are given for plotly express

Comment: I didn't understand. Your problem is with modifying the dataset that you do or suppose you use filter and your problem is with fetching data from the dataset over and over?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you include code with your question (maybe using a small sample data set instead of your actual data set)? It's hard to tell what exactly you're asking – when you say interactive and user changing the range, do you mean that you're using `plotly-dash` to regenerate the figure?